# Why does inferring the first tuple value from string[] lose it's type?

Tags: typescript

When inferring first tuple value from string array, it seems like TypeScript loses the information that the inferred value must be string. Why is the type lost?

```
type Test<T extends string> = true;
// Head should be known to be string since T is string[]
type Example<T extends string[]> = T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? // Type 'Head' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
    Test<Head>
  : never;
```

I know I can solve the issue by doing `infer Head extends string` instead of `infer Head`, but I don't understand why it's necessary. Is there some scenario I'm missing where `Head` could be something else than `string`?

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwA8MoQB7AgOwCbykQCcBLbAcwD4oBeKYIgVwgG4AoUSKAUXQEMAtmAA2EFGkw58hBmXIBtALrU6qDFjwF5ZAGYQiUABIQ+uADRQAdNd37YfEsMVsoUAPxQA9J9jhoAcmNTfyhcAHsEKGww4EI+YBJ4HRB6AAtoAGMw7GIHbFj-Yjl-SxdXWARkINxKMoAuKIgAN30WIA)

Comment: This a missing feature, requested at [ms/TS#51108](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51108).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Related: (1) Are you aware of [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) and that the first element of `string[]` can actually be `undefined` (for an array of length `0`)? (2) Why not use `T[0]` to index the first element?

Comment: @jcalz Yes that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really missing anything; the type of `Head` will always be assignable to `string` in your example, but the compiler just doesn't see it.

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#51108](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51108) to use information from [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to further narrow the type of [type parameters `infer`red in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).  If you want to see this implemented, it wouldn't hurt to give that issue a  and possibly describe your use case if it's novel and compelling.  It probably wouldn't *help* much, but it wouldn't hurt.

Until and unless the feature is implemented, you'll have to work around it.  The easiest workaround is probably to use a redundant [`extends` constraint on `infer`red type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables), as you mentioned.